# GruntJS specify boolean config based on environment

Tags: pug, gruntjs

I have a `Gruntfile` that looks something like this (simplified for the example):

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
  grunt.initConfig

    config:
      dev:
        options:
          variables:
            debug: true
      dist:
        options:
          variables:
            debug: false

    jade:
      templates:
        options:
          client: true
          compileDebug: '<%= grunt.config.get("debug") %>'
        files:
          'public/templates.js': ['src/jade/templates/**/*.jade']

  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-config'
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-jade'
```

The problem is that `grunt-config` (or maybe it's the template parsing) converts all of its options to strings, but the Jade compiler is checking all of its boolean flag options as booleans (`if (compileDebug !== false)`). So even when I run `grunt config:dist jade`, it still generates templates with the debugging logic included.

I know I could get around this by duplicating the Jade config into two different targets, but I'd like to keep my Gruntfile as DRY as possible. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: seems pretty broken to me

Comment: It's cofeescript, that's why seems "broken"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to do this so I made a grunt plugin with the functionality here:

https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-reconfigure